# search multiple keywords recursively in a folder path

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file which contains multiple keywords one on each line for e.g.

- Key1
- Key2
- Key3
- Key4

then I have a set of sub directories which contain many files. I need a linux grep or sed command equivalent which will search all keywords recursively in all the sub directories and print the file names for me.

I can do `find . | xargs grep "key1"` but that I have to do for each keyword. I need one command which does for all Key1, Key2, Key3 etc.

Please help with this issue.

Comment: Have you done `man grep` and looked at the `-f` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
grep -rlf file .
```

`-r` is for recursive

`-l` is to print only the names of files containing matches

`-f` takes pattern from file, one per line.

Comment: Thanks that really works. Is there any way I can print which file matched which input pattern?

Answer (score 0):

AND pattern for 2 keywords

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q word1 {} \; -exec grep -l word2 {} \;
```

AND pattern for 3 keywords

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q word1 {} \; -exec grep -q word2 {} \; -exec grep -l word3 {} \;
```